# Maintain contentOffset of UITextView on orientation change

Tags: ios, uitextview

Is it possible to change the content offset of a UITextView so when the user moves from portrait to landscape (or vice versa), the text which is visible to them remains the same?

So if the user was at (in portrait mode)

```
....some text....
....some text2....
....I'm here.... //this is the visible area
....more text....
```

moves to landscape, it should be

```
....some text....some text2....
....I'm here....more text.... //this is the visible area
.....
```

The UITextView is non-editable but scrollable.

Comment: I've just tested it, and it seems that `UITextView` does this automatically for you. Could you describe your problem more?

Comment: I am using textviews inside a scrollview. And on scroll, I have to layout the views again so they respect the view size. But when I do, the scroll position of the textview changes. So just want to know if it is possible to find the user's current scroll position (relative) and set it manually when orientation changes

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a short, self contained, compilable example :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var textView: UITextView!
    var percentOfScroll:CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectZero)

        self.textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        self.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.textView.editable = false

        self.textView.text = "Lorem ipsum... some longish text"

        self.view.addSubview(self.textView)

        let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
        let rightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -10)
        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 44)
        let centerConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.textView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addConstraints([leftConstraint, rightConstraint, topConstraint, centerConstraint])
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let contentSize = self.textView.contentSize
        let newOffset = contentSize.height * percentOfScroll

        self.textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: newOffset)
    }

    override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        let contentSize = self.textView.contentSize
        let contentOffset = self.textView.contentOffset

        self.percentOfScroll = contentOffset.y / contentSize.height
    }

}
```

The idea is to get the amount of scrolled content in relation to its height before rotation (`viewWillTransitionToSize`) and using it calculate new `contentOffset` after (`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is also called after size change).

Bear in mind that this doesn't give a 100% precise result, but I haven't been able to come up with anything better , and maybe this will be enough for you.